# Otherwise, do it

Tags: phrase-usage, grammaticality, phrase-request

> - If a jump statement is a part of a guard, don’t follow it with `Else If` or `Else`.
> - Otherwise, do it.

I don't understand whether the use of "Otherwise, do it" is correct or not. It's perfectly OK in my native language, but I cannot find good English examples. And it makes me think that something is wrong here.

Comment: It's fine, but would be slightly cleaner in my eyes without "it": "Otherwise, do."

Comment: @TypeIA Thanks a lot :-) Is it correct that it must be "Otherwise, do" and not "Do otherwise"? In other words, "Do otherwise" has completely different meaning?

Comment: Yes, "do otherwise" means "do something else." It's not at all what you want here.